# No Server in SQL Server 2014 Management Studio

Tags: sql-server

I've downloaded a full installation of SQL Server 2014 Management Studio via the university. When I open the Management Studio, the server name is missing. I've checked in the configuration manager, and nothing is listed at all. I have not had any success googling it, so now I ask the question here.

Her is a snip of the features which I could select in the installation:

[image]

Comment: You haven't installed the sever, only the management studio

Comment: Thank you. So how do I install the server. Is that done by installer the sql express version or?

Comment: Trust me; I've spent alot of time on this. As you have guessed I'm totally new to SQL, and since yesterday I didn't even know that SQL magement studio existed.

Comment: I did exactly what is shown her https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5TorrsIdwHQ

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42299 

I Googled: "sql server 2014 express download"

Comment: And this will direct me to the first question. "So how do I install the server. Is that done by installing the sql express version or?"

And since you are posting that particular link, I guess that's a "yes".